# clear polygons with setMap(null) before updating with new geojson

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm trying to clear all my polygon objects before I import new geoJSON data and create new objects. I can't seem to get the setMap(null) function to work correctly. Hopefully someone can kindly let me know where I am failing.

Thank you

```
var map;
function removeAllMarkers(){// removes all markers from map
//console.log(data);
for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
delpolygon = new google.maps.Poly({
    position: data[i]
})
delpoly.setMap(null)
}   
data.length = 0;
//markersInfoArray.length = 0;
};

// ajax request to load json data
var data;
function pullNewData () {
var newRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
newRequest.open('GET', 'json_template.json', true);
newRequest.onload = function() {
//data = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")")
data = JSON.parse(newRequest.responseText)

console.log(data);
sector_callback(data);
removeAllMarkers(data);
};
newRequest.send();
};

//setInterval(pullNewData,5000);

// function to load map into body when page loads
function initialize() { 
var kansas_city = new google.maps.LatLng(39.316858,-94.963194);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: kansas_city,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
}

// ajax request to load json data
var data;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'json_template.json', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
//data = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")")
data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
//console.log(data);
sector_callback(data);
};
xhr.send();

function createClickablePoly(poly, html) {
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
});
}
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});        

var allPolygons = [];
function sector_callback() {
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();        
for (var i = 0, len = data.features.length; i < len; i++) {
    var coords = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
    siteNames = data.features[i].properties.Name; // added for site names
    var path = [];
            //console.log(siteNames);
            //console.log(coords);
    for ( var j = 0, len2 = coords.length; j < len2; j++ ){ // pull out each     set of coords and create a map object
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0])
        bounds.extend(pt);
        path.push(pt);

        //path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0]));
    }

    var polygons = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: path,
        strokeColor: "#000000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#000000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map
    });
    createClickablePoly(polygons, siteNames);

    google.maps.event.addListener(polygons, 'mouseover', function() {
    var currentPolygon = this;

    currentPolygon.setOptions({ // setOptions is a method and properties below
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
        fillColor: "#FF0000"
        })
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(polygons, 'mouseout', function() {
    var currentPolygon = this;
    currentPolygon.setOptions({ 
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        fillColor: "#000000"
        })
    });
    allPolygons.push(polygons); 
  }

}
console.log(allPolygons);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new `Poly`, store it in an array, say `allPolygons`, so you can reference them later.

Then iterate over this Array, and call `setMap(null)` on every `Poly` inside.

Comment: I am attempting to declare an array allPolygons outside the loop, but when I try to push the polygons into the allPolygons array within the for loop the array is empty when I access it with console.log(allPolygons). I updated the code above to show my attempts.

Comment: If you're running exactly what's in the code snippet window, you're logging (polygons) not (allPolygons). Also, double check where you're pushing the polygon into the array. It's happening outside the scope of the for loop.

Comment: You are correct. I updated the console log to (allPolygons). I am still not able to push the elements to the array allPolygons. The console.log is showing "[ ]" which if I understand correctly is an empty array. Is this a scope issue? Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: As rick already mentioned, you're trying to push things into `allPolygons` outside of the `for` loop. You need to do it inside of the loop, and push every `Poly` you create to `allPolygons`

Comment: Okay. I put the push inside the for loop scope, but the array is still empty when I log it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: The callback happens asynchronously, so basically you'll end up creating the array and logging the empty array before it's ever filled by the callback. Move the log inside the callback but outside the loop that's populating the array.

Comment: Thank you Rick. I can now see the array in console. How would I then remove the polygons say in 10 seconds after the map loads? Thanks.

Comment: Add a listener for the map event 'tilesloaded', set a timeout for 10 seconds, loop through your array and setMap(null) for each item. Also, don't forget to select doesterr's answer =)